# iPhone SDK - Relative position inside another control?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

How can I tell the relative position (x & y) of uiimageview B relative (or the "inside of" position ??) of UIImageView B?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to know the position of a view respect another one use `[aView convertPoint:toView:]` or `[aView convertRect:toView:]`, you can find the documentation of this functions [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint%3atoView%3a) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertRect%3atoView%3a).

Answer (score 1):

frame is the property you are looking for, it gives you the origin and size of a view, relative to its superview

```
UIView *a = //outer view
UIView *b = //inner view
[a addSubview:b];

CGRect bFrame = b.frame; 
NSLog(@"%@", NSStrinFromCGRect(bFrame)); //will be something like (100, 100, 40, 20)
```

edit: I didnt realise they werent subviews (I dont use IB), so you will need to convert to the coord system of a:

```
   CGRect bFrame = [a convertRect:b.frame fromView:b.superView];
```

Comment: do you mind providing a code example for the comparison of two controls? if possible?

Comment: This might not be the case here as B doesn't look like it's subview of A (you can't really do that inside Interface Builder). Just adding it to A as a subview in code would most likely mess up the UI as frame would then be relative to A instead of their shared superview. So @tkanzakic's solution is better.